# Redshift how to update the last octec of IP address column to another value

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
a.  123.12.1 -> 123.12.999
b.  123.12.100.0 -> 123.12.100.999
c.  123.123 -> 123.999
```

I have a Redshift table with one IP address column, cases as above, I used substring and position function nested many time to match the requirement, but I want to learn if is there any other method to do

Comment: case when the third dot is existing then substring to get xxx.xxx.xxx + '.999'
when the third dot is not existing and the second dot is existing then substring to get xxx.xxx + '.999'
when the second dot is not existing and the first dot is existing then to get xxx + '.999'

Answer (score 0):

a cleaner way is using a Python UDF that splits the string by dot symbol, and returns all elements but the last one, with 999 appended. the body of the function is below (`val` is the parameter, look how to create the function in official Redshift docs)

```
return '.'.join(val.split('.')[:-1])+'.999'
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use split. the easiest way to update your values is:

```
update table set ip = regexp_replace(ip, '[.][0-9]{1,3}$','.999');
```

see [redshift regexp_replace function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html)

the `$` character makes sure that only the last octet is replaced.